# use java variable inside ajax call

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp

I have a periodically calling Ajax call. I use this ajax call to invoke an endpoint. Below I have mentioned my jsp file(polling.jsp). The service has hosted in tomcat server. Expected output from the variable title is "Metallica". But I get below error in firebug without getting the alert.
ReferenceError: Metallica is not defined
alert(Metallica);

I need to check weather the web service is calling time to time as I defined. If I did not put the alert ,

```
alert(<%=name%>);
```

then I can see ajax call is working properly in firebug. But I need to put the alert their to get the response form the web service.

polling.jsp

```
<script>
    <%
    Client client = Client.create();
    %>

    var set_delay = 5000,

            callout = function () {
                $.ajax({

                })
                        .done(function (response) {

                            <%
                               WebResource webResource = client
             .resource("http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/json/metallica/get");

              ClientResponse response1 = webResource.accept("application/json")
             .get(ClientResponse.class);

     if (response1.getStatus() != 200) {
         throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                 + response1.getStatus());
     }

     String output = response1.getEntity(String.class);
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     Track track=gson.fromJson(output,Track.class);
     String name=track.getName().toString();
         %>

      alert(<%=name%>);
                        })
                        .always(function () {
                            setTimeout(callout, set_delay);
                        });
            };
    callout();
</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: put quotes around the variable eg `alert(
"<%=name%>");`

Comment: It worked. Sorry for the unawareness. I'm new to ajax and javascript. Let me just mark your answer as correct. :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping up in double quotes

```
alert("<%=name%>");
```

Since `<%=name%>` will be replaced by value say `StackOverflow` so you are actually doing

```
alert(StackOverflow);// will not work as StackOverflow is not an Object/Variable
```

Hence you need to do `alert("StackOverflow");`